# UpdateView crea nuevos elementos de un Formset, no los actualiza

Tags: django, django-forms

hace dos meses que empecé a usar Django. Ahora mismo tengo las CBV de un formulario con dos elementos, un Modelo Padre y un Modelo Hijo que pueden ser multiples. La parte de Create, Detail, List y Delete las tengo funcionales. El problema lo tengo a la hora de editar con el formulario del modelo Padre con multiples Formsets del Modelo Hijo, ya que a la hora de guardar la nueva información, crea nuevos elementos en vez de actualizarlos (Por ejemplo, si edito 3 instancias del Hijo, me crea 3 objetos con la información nueva y me mantiene los 3 hijos anteriores sin modificar).

Al crear los nuevos objetos hijos, puedo ver que la información es correcta, que los guarda como hijos del Padre, etc. La información es correcta, pero algún error en mi código hace que no relacione los hijos del UpdateView con los existentes, por eso crea los nuevos objetos.

Este es mi código (*Entrada es el Padre, con multiples instáncias de BalaMateriesPrimeres*):

**models.py**

```
class Entrada(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entrades'

    data_hora = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    num_factura = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    cost_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
    quilos_total = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    descripcio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    observacions = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    proveidor = models.ForeignKey(Proveidor, related_name='entrades', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Metodos varios


class BalaMateriesPrimeres(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bales de Materies Primeres'

    magatzem = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    quilos = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    cost_unitari = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    cost_material = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=4)
    observacions = models.TextField(blank=True)
    SI = 's'
    NO = 'n'
    DESCONEGUT = 'd'
    PREASSIGNADA_CHOICES = (
        (SI, 'Sí'),
        (NO, 'No'),
        (DESCONEGUT, 'Desconegut'),
    )
    pre_assignada = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=PREASSIGNADA_CHOICES,
        default=DESCONEGUT,
    )
    barcode = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    SI = 's'
    NO = 'n'
    EN_PROCES = 'p'
    CONSUMIDA_CHOICES = (
        (SI, 'Sí'),
        (NO, 'No'),
        (EN_PROCES, 'En procés'),
    )

    consumida = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=CONSUMIDA_CHOICES,
        default=NO,
    )
    material = models.ForeignKey('Material', related_name='materials', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fabrica = models.ForeignKey('Fabrica', related_name='bales_materials', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    num_entrada = models.ForeignKey(
        Entrada, related_name='bales_materies_primeres', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Metodos varios
```

**forms.py**

```
class EntradaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entrada
        exclude = ()


class BalaMateriesPrimeresForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BalaMateriesPrimeres
        fields = ['quilos', 'material', 'cost_unitari', 'cost_material']

BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Entrada, BalaMateriesPrimeres, form=BalaMateriesPrimeresForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class EntradaUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entrada
    fields = [...]
    template_name_suffix = '_update'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(EntradaUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Utilizo esto para traerme los elementos hijo. Puede ser que esto sea lo que está mal?
        if self.request.POST:
            data['bala_form'] = BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['bala_form'] = BalaMateriesPrimeres.objects.filter(num_entrada=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):

        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        qs = BalaMateriesPrimeres.objects.filter(num_entrada=self.get_object())
        formsets = BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet(self.request.POST, queryset=qs)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            if formsets.is_valid():
                instances = formsets.save(commit=False)
                for instance in instances:
                    instance.instance = self.object
                    instance.num_entrada = Entrada.objects.get(pk=self.object.id)
                    instance.save()

        return super(EntradaUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Con esto consigo que me guarde los elementos como nuevas balas (Si carga 3 balas, crea 3 balas nuevas sin relación con las anteriores). Llevo 2 dias probando y no sé cómo hacerlo, así que agradeceria que alguien me apunte a qué está fallando o a algún ejemplo funcional com multiples Formsets.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema: En get_context_data guardaba la información del Formset peró no la pasaba al template de forma adecuada. Dejo aquí la forma correcta por si alguien necesita ayuda sobre cómo modificar un Padre con multiples Hijos:

```
class PadreUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Padre
    form_class = PadreForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        hijo_form = HijoFormSet(instance = self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form = form, hijo_form = hijo_form ))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        hijo_form = HijoFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

        if (form.is_valid() and hijo_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, bala_form)
        return self.form_invalid(form, bala_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, bala_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        hijo_form.instance = self.object
        hijo_form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Atención: MUY importante no olvidar de colocar en el template en la iteración del hijo_form, el hijo.id. De lo contrario, nos dará form_invalid:

```
{% for hijo in hijo_form %}
{{ hijo.id }}
....
{% endfor %}
```